# google maps polylines wont appear?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have checked with a previously working version with firebug
every line object has a Ec member which has a $ member with the coordinates values latitude and longitude.

but with my new version of code when the lines dont appear and on checking these values I get infinity in firebug at all four cordinates of a line with 2 endpoints

```
stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPath.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPlanCoordinates,
                    strokeColor: 'white',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                    strokeWeight: 0.5
                  }));
            stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPath[stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPath.length-1].setMap(map);
```

Comment: what does firebug say about `stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPath[stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPath.length-1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling setMap, why don't you just do:

```
stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPath.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: stars[thisMarker.starsref].flightPlanCoordinates,
                    strokeColor: 'white',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                    strokeWeight: 0.5,
                    map: map
                  }));
```